# Which file system is better for Ceph?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, xfs, openstack

I've read the Ceph [OS recommendations](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/start/os-recommendations/#notes) document, but still I have a question.
Which file system is better for Ceph?

XFS, ext4, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to ceph documents,they recommend configuring Ceph to use the XFS file system in the near term, and btrfs in the long term once it is stable enough for production and at the end, ext4.

[document 1](http://ceph.com/docs/argonaut/rec/filesystem/)

[document 2](http://ceph.com/docs/master/rados/configuration/filesystem-recommendations/)

[document 3](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Kernel-Log-Coming-in-2-6-37-Part-2-File-systems-1148305.html%3Fanchor=btrfs)

Answer (score 1):

[Ceph's recommendation for the choice of filesystem](http://ceph.com/docs/master/rados/configuration/filesystem-recommendations/#filesystems) is between `btrfs` and `XFS`. `ext4` is not recommended.

From that page:

> We currently recommend XFS for production deployments. We recommend btrfs for testing, development, and any non-critical deployments. We believe that btrfs has the correct feature set and roadmap to serve Ceph in the long-term, but XFS and ext4 provide the necessary stability for today’s deployments. btrfs development is proceeding rapidly: users should be comfortable installing the latest released upstream kernels and be able to track development activity for critical bug fixes.

I would say that the forward-looking choice is `btrfs`.